# The verb "to lean"

Tags: verbs

I have a question regarding the usage of the verb "to lean".
From the dictionary I understand that the verb "to lean" has, among others, the following meanings:

1. To bend or slant away from the vertical.
   (In my opinion movement is implied)
2. To incline the weight of the body so as to be supported: leaning against the doorpost.
   (In my opinion no movement is implied)

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lean

Consider the following examples:

1. She was leaning over the counter, trying to reach for her purse, when he came in.
   (Movement implied as when he came in, she was in the act of leaning over the table)
2. She was leaned over the counter, trying to reach for her purse, when he came in.
   (No movement implied as when he came in, she was already in that position)

As "to bend over" is a synonym of "to lean over", let's replace "lean over" above with "bend over":

1. She was bending over the counter, trying to reach for her purse, when he came in.
   (Movement implied)
2. She was bent over the counter, trying to reach for her purse, when he came in.
   (No movement implied)

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lean+over

Do you think my interpretation is correct?

Comment: No, _leaning_ can certainly be used without implied movement, such as the famous _Leaning Tower of Pisa_.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Well, I can understand that we can have "the leaning tower of Pisa" and "leaning trees on the beach", but I do not believe that we can say "X was leaning over Y" and to understand "X was being in a static position over Y". What do you reckon?

Comment: I have no problem visualizing "X leaning over Y" as static, in the same way that "John was leaning against the wall" is almost _certainly_ describing a static situation.

Comment: I see. But don't you think I am using this meaning "to incline, deviate, or bend from a vertical position", while in your example you are using this meaning "to incline the weight of the body so as to be supported" as in "leaning against the railing"? And I agree that your example "John was leaning against the wall." is certainly describing a static situation. :)

Comment: Gerunds (the *-ing* form of verbs) can have both dynamic as well as static implication. In the static case, the gerund has the character of a noun (being the "state") and in the dynamic, either a noun or a verb.

Comment: When speaking of inanimate objects, _lean_ implies no motion; if motion is intended, a different verb (like _bend_ or _slant_, which can imply movement) is used. _Lean_ implies resistance to gravity in a vertically-oriented state, and may refer to humans or to anything that might fall down if unsupported. Movement with human subjects is not necessarily implied at coding time -- she could be bending or leaning over the counter and still be motionless -- but some motion is entailed to get into the position.

Comment: I lean towards the position that it's entirely a matter of opinion whether I'm *statically* or *dynamically* adopting any particular position. So I'm closevoting as Primarily Opinion-based.

Comment: It's not so much opinion as dependent on context. There are ambiguous uses, and a careful speaker will try to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the verb in its past progressive form with the "ing" added which, in my opinion, is causing you to visualize "lean" as a motion.  Almost all examples I can think of using "lean" are static.  To make this clear think of the sentence, "He was sitting in the chair when I entered the room."  This doesn't mean that there was movement...unless you add "down" as in "He was sitting down in the chair when I entered the room."  (Should it be "in" or "onto?"). Adding "over" does not imply motion in this case.